# Remove quotes from the start and end of a string

Tags: c#, string

I have the string

```
"{ "type" : "Stage_FF_Hot_Alerts__c"}"
```

I want to it be

```
{ "type" : "Stage_FF_Hot_Alerts__c"}
```

i.e. I want to remove quotes from start and end. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So what is your problem? Did you tried and had some problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Trim`:

```
var a = "\"{ \"type\" : \"Stage_FF_Hot_Alerts__c\"}\"";
var b = a.Trim('"');
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

It will remove all leading and trailing quotation marks.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/JPYSEE95978)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
var quotedString = "\"hello\"";
var unQuotedString = quotedString.TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"');
```